# Redirect based on URL/Query Parameters

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url-parameters, query-string

I basically just want to redirect the user to a different site based on the URL (or query) parameters but I have no idea how.

If the URL is `https://www.tamoghnak.tk/redirect?link=https://www.tamoghnak.tk/gobob` then it should redirect to https://www.tamoghnak.tk /gobob.

If the URL is `https://www.tamoghnak.tk/redirect?link=https://stackoverflow.com` then it should redirect to https://stackoverflow.com and so on (Redirect to any site in parameters).

How would I do this? (In Node, JS, HTML, etc.)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Including your code would be helpful. You can get the query string from a URL in Node in many ways. Are you creating a simple HTTP server or using a framework like Express?

Comment: I'm using Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Express it could be like this:

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/from', (req, res) => {
  // The optional first parameter to `res.redirect()` is a numeric
  // HTTP status.
  res.redirect(301, '/to');
});
app.get('/to', (req, res) => res.send('Hello, World!'));

const server = await app.listen(3000);

const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/from'); // "Hello, World!" res.data;
```

link https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/redirect

All you have to do is take the parameter from the get request and paste its value into the redirect.

My code:

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/from', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(301, req.query.link);
});
```

Comment: @TamoghnaK13 Next time, you'd better write the technology stack you're using. I was lucky, I guessed, but I might not have guessed.